# ValueError: Found array with dim 4. Estimator expected <= 2. what to do?

Tags: image, model, dataset, dimension, valueerror

I have loaded some image data-sets from a directory and want to classify those images . I have resized it into (64,64,3) sizes images but unable to fit into the model .

It says : 
ValueError: Found array with dim 4. Estimator expected <= 2.
What should be done ?

Comment: It would probably be useful to see some of the code you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say, `X` is your training data with the shape of (N_samples, 64,64,3)
 `Found array with dim 4` means that you have your images in above shown shape.

```
N_samples, img_width, img_height, ch = X.shape
X_reshaped = X.reshape(N_samples, -1 )
```

does the job here